# switch keyboard from qwerty to number pad and vice versa

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I want to adjust editText input type such that first I want to show number only on keybord with a button for switching keyborad from numbers keypad to qwerty .I have find many similar question related to this but nothing has worked out.

I have tried to do this by setting ime action button.Don't know whether it is right or not but it is not working for me.Is there any other alternative for this?

Here is the code :

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloword.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/ed"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo|actionNext|actionSend|actionDone"
        android:imeActionLabel="abc"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/my_ime"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText ed;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        ed.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(arg1==R.id.my_ime)
                {
                    Log.e("inside", "inside");
                    ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: onClick of switch keyboard button change InputType of edittext..

Comment: Isn't the "standard" keyboard enough? It already has what you need apart that it doesn't start with numbers. If your problem is forcing the user to follow a specific pattern for the input, you could use a TextWatcher on the EditText.

Comment: @praveen that is what I tried but dint work.

Comment: @mave I just want to show keypad with only numbers with a switch button to change keyboard with qwerty ....can you please explain your answer

Comment: I could it using changing input type.. Check this video once to clarify if this is what you wanted https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzu9GRweTvvfR1hvZ2ltZFlxNFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Praveen I have a question that can I do that on ime action button ??

Comment: You mean, you want to change action button instead of full keyboard?

Comment: I want to change keyboard on pressing action button .In video you have given it is done by switch button.@Praveen